# Highcharts won't display data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying out highcharts' time series zoomable table. I get my data via:

```
$.getJSON(
        '/Data/DailyTime',
        function (data) {
            var v = [];
            var temp;
            data.forEach(function (item) {
                temp = "[" + (item[0]+989) + ", " + item[1] + "]";
                v.push(temp);
            });
         alert(v); //line 10

         var opt_dailytime = {
                // ....
                // ....
                // ....
                series: [{
                        type: 'area',
                        data:  v
                        }]
                // ....
                // ....
                // ....
```

the alert's output in line 10 is:

```
[1540772030989, 1],[1540772041989, 1],[1540772102989, 1],[1540793888989, 1], 
[1540805114989, 1],[1540807200989, 1],[1540820269989, 1],[1540831608989, 1], 
[1540832150989, 1],[1540832322989, 1],[1540833600989, 1],[1540834662989, 1], 
[1540834670989, 1],[1540834892989, 1],[1540835639989, 1],[1540835744989, 1], 
[1540836013989, 1],[1540836087989, 1],[1540836109989, 1],[1540842529989, 1], 
[1540842721989, 1],[1540847258989, 1],[1540847468989, 1],[1540856547989, 1]
```

when i input this data manually in highchart options it gets displayed correctly:

```
series: [{
    type: 'area',
    data: [[1540772030989, 1],[1540772041989, 1],[1540772102989, 1],
          //........................................................
           [1540847258989, 1],[1540847468989, 1],[1540856547989, 1]]
}]
```

but when i do something like:

```
series: [{
    type: 'area',
    data:  v
}]
```

or

```
series: [{
    type: 'area',
    data: "[" + v + "]"
}]
```

no data gets displayed..

sorry, I know I'm must be missing something very obvious here but I'm kinda new to javascript so please have mercy ;m;

Here is my whole javascript but with manually added values:
http://jsfiddle.net/vkm3hxo2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing strings to your array, it needs to be arrays or objects.

This line:

```
temp = "[" + (item[0]+989) + ", " + item[1] + "]";
```

Needs to be

```
temp = [parseInt(item[0])+989, parseFloat(item[1])]
```

Or

```
temp = {x: parseInt(item[0])+989, y: parseFloat(item[1])}
```